# Any feature in BigQuery that can migrate a whole dataset in another project w/o executing copy data?

Tags: google-bigquery

While our project grows, at some point we realized that we need to create new projects and reorganize our dataset. One case is that we need to isolate one dataset from others into another new project. I know that I can do it by copying tables one by one through API and then delete the old ones. But when it comes to over a thousand of tables, it's really consumes a lot of time as the copying api is executed as a job and it takes time. Is it possible to just change reference(or path) of a dataset?

**Follow up**
I tried copy tables using batch request. I got 200 OK in all request, but the tables just didn't get copied. I wonder why and how to get the real result. Here's my code:

```
    public async Task CopyTableToProjectInBatchAsync(IList<TableList.TablesData> fromTables, string toProjectId)
    {
        var request = new BatchRequest(BigQueryService);
        foreach (var tableData in fromTables)
        {
            string fromDataset = tableData.TableReference.DatasetId;
            string fromTableId = tableData.TableReference.TableId;
            Logger.Info("copying table {0}...",tableData.Id);
            request.Queue<JobReference>(CreateTableCopyRequest(fromDataset, fromTableId, toProjectId),
            (content, error, i, message) =>
            {
                Logger.Info("#content:\n" + content);
                Logger.Info("#error:\n" + error);
                Logger.Info("#i:\n" + i);
                Logger.Info("#message:\n" + message);
            });
        }
        await request.ExecuteAsync();
    }

   private IClientServiceRequest CreateTableCopyRequest(string fromDatasetId, string fromTableId, string toProjectId,
        string toDatasetId=null, string toTableId=null)
    {
        if (toDatasetId == null)
            toDatasetId = fromDatasetId;
        if (toTableId == null)
            toTableId = fromTableId;
        TableReference sourceTableReference = new TableReference
        {
            ProjectId = _account.ProjectId,
            DatasetId = fromDatasetId,
            TableId = fromTableId
        };
        TableReference targetTableReference = new TableReference
        {
            ProjectId = toProjectId,
            DatasetId = toDatasetId,
            TableId = toTableId
        };
        JobConfigurationTableCopy copyConfig = new JobConfigurationTableCopy
        {
            CreateDisposition = "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            DestinationTable = targetTableReference,
            SourceTable = sourceTableReference
        };
        JobReference jobRef = new JobReference {JobId = GenerateJobID("copyTable"), ProjectId = _account.ProjectId};
        JobConfiguration jobConfig = new JobConfiguration {Copy = copyConfig};
        Job job = new Job {Configuration = jobConfig, JobReference = jobRef};

        return BigQueryService.Jobs.Insert(job, _account.ProjectId);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there's currently no move or rename operation in BigQuery. The best way to move your data is to copy it and delete the original.

**Follow-up answer**: Your batch request created the copy jobs, but you need to wait for them to complete and then observe the result. You can use the BigQuery web UI or run "bq ls -j" from the command line to see recent jobs.

Comment: I put a follow-up above

Comment: Also, do you think it's possible to be a feature in the future?

Comment: and my understanding is that copy will work only if source and destination datasets have the same data location

Comment: foxwendy: Updated my answer. Mikhail: Correct, you can only copy within a location. To work around that limitation, you can export to Google Cloud Storage, transfer to new location, and re-import.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant by data location, you mean US and others right? our tables are all in default one(the US I think).

Comment: @JeremyCondit I ended up making around 400 tables copied at once, however, the rest, about 600 (two parts added up to 1000) of them failed. The exceptions I saw for now is taskcancelled exception. I need to handle those exceptions and make sure every of my thousands table has been copied, could you illustrate more on how I can do that?

Comment: foxwendy:yes. we have multiple locations, so we had to use workaround mentioned by Jeremy above

Comment: foxwendy: Use the jobs.get method to check for job status. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/get

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem than @JeremyCondit, but my projects are in different regions. We have lots of projects in different regions due to the nature of our business and I see this batch job copy tables not working cross region a limitation. Is there any possibility to have this feature in the future? Also I got the error: "Not Implemented" doing so, which is a very misleading explanation. I can't find the logs for my job, can I know if that error is due to the fact that the copy does not work cross regions? Where can I find the log for the batch job? Thank you

Comment: We'd like to provide cross-region table copy at some point in the future, but we have specific plans or ETA right now. All available information about your job's status and output is available from the jobs.get method linked above.

Answer (score 7):

You can first copy BigQuery dataset to the new project, then delete the original dataset.

The copy dataset UI is similar to copy table. Just click "copy dataset" button from the source dataset, and specify the destination dataset in the pop-up form. See screenshot below. Check out the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets) for more use cases.

**Copy dataset button**

[image]

**Copy dataset form**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There's no built-in feature but I helped write a tool that we've open-sourced that will do this for you: https://github.com/uswitch/big-replicate.

It will let you synchronise/copy tables between projects or datasets (within the same project). Most of the details are in the project's [README](https://github.com/uswitch/big-replicate/blob/master/README.md) but for reference it looks a little like:

```
java -cp big-replicate-standalone.jar \
  uswitch.big_replicate.sync \
  --source-project source-project-id \
  --source-dataset 98909919 \
  --destination-project destination-project-id \
  --destination-dataset 98909919
```

You can set options that will control how many tables to copy, how many jobs run concurrently and where to store the intermediate data in Cloud Storage. The destination dataset must already exist but this means you'll be able to copy data between locations too (US, EU, Asia etc.).

Binaries are built on [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/gh/uswitch/big-replicate) and published to [GitHub releases](https://github.com/uswitch/big-replicate/releases).

Answer (score 5):

A short shell script which copies all tables from a dataset to another dataset:

```
export SOURCE_DATASET=$1  # project1:dataset
export DEST_PREFIX=$2  # project2:dataset2.any_prefix_
for f in `bq ls $SOURCE_DATASET |grep TABLE | awk '{print $1}'`
do
  export CP_COMMAND="bq cp $SOURCE_DATASET.$f $DEST_PREFIX$f"
  echo $CP_COMMAND
  echo `$CP_COMMAND`
done
```

Comment: This worked for me. Don't forget to end the DEST_PREFIX with a "." if you don't want a prefix.