# Bigquery migration from one environment to another environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We are using Google Bigquery and having multiple Google accounts for different environments say development and production.

Ex: devbigquery@gmail.com - Development environment
prodbigquery@gmail.com - Production environment.

I don't see any option to migrate tables and views from one environment to another environment. How can we migrate tables and views from the development environment to the production environment?

Comment: I think there is no direct way. Have you checked this? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32724767/any-feature-in-bigquery-that-can-migrate-a-whole-dataset-in-another-project-w-o

Answer (score 2):

In BigQuery web console, click drop down button adjacent to table and select copy table option
In copy table you can select projects like Dev, QA, Prod and also Dataset in that project.
Table will be copied into the new environment

[image: Picture for copying table]